# How can I search for [ inside a my MySQL column?

Tags: mysql

`SELECT * FROM mytable where print_pattern LIKE '[%#[%,]' ESCAPE '#';`

I want to search either for `[` or `,`.

Comment: With the `LIKE` comparison the `%` character is a wildcard that matches zero, one or more of any characters. An alternative to the `LIKE` comparison is regular expression punctuation soup ... to match a `[` or `,` we could do **`print_pattern REGEXP '\\[|,'`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for `[` or `,` in any position of the string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
   (print_pattern LIKE '%[%') OR
   (print_pattern LIKE '%,%')
;
```

I don't see the need of `ESCAPE '#'` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ESCAPE`. A simple `LIKE` statement with `OR` condition will work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE 
    (print_patterns LIKE '%[%'
    OR print_patterns LIKE '%,%')
```

You can read up on Pattern Matching here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html